# Firestore security rule logging of variable values

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

   match /companies/{companyName=**}{
        allow read,write: if isUserAuthorized(companyName,get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(companyName)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company) == true;
   }
  }
}
function isUserAuthorized(requestedCompanyName,userCompanyName) {
  return requestedCompanyName == userCompanyName;
}
```

In the above rule of firestore I am trying to make sure that only employees from a company can access data of that company. The data structure on firestore looks like the following screenshot.
where data is saved in this path /companies/{companyName}/users/{uid}/company

[image]

But when I try to save I get `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.` js error.

- Is there anything apparent I am doing wrong?
- Is there any logging that happens on firestore side where I can see what request was made and what were the values of variables used in the rules.
- Or is there a way to test the rules?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the minimal code that produces that message?

Comment: A Firestore Security Rules log similar to that of Cloud Functions would be very useful for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but in case it helps anyone else:

I think that the problem is in the "match" statement, here:

```
match /companies/{companyName=**}{
    allow read,write: if isUserAuthorized(companyName,get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(companyName)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company) == true;
}
```

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure),

> When using the recursive wildcard syntax, the wildcard variable will contain the entire matching path segment, even if the document is located in a deeply nested subcollection. For example, the rules listed above would match a document located at /cities/SF/landmarks/coit_tower, and the value of the document variable would be SF/landmarks/coit_tower.

when the final term in your matching path ends with `=**`, you are assigning the entire remainder of the path to the variable `companyname`.  So, taking values from your example, you may expect `companyname` to contain `spoor`, but in fact it contains `/spoor/users/iKHFF...` unless the request is specifically for the "spoor" document.  Thus the path in your `get()` is not pointing to the correct document.

Indeed, it would be very nice if there were debugging tools available, but so far I have not found any other than trial and error.  It's unfortunate, and will hopefully be fixed before they exit beta.

Answer (score 1):

For now there is no way to test the rules.

you can try this

```
match /companies/{companyName=**}{
    allow read,write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(companyName)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).company in [$(companyName)] || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(companyName)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company in [$(companyName)];
}
```

which says write if `path/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company` has the `companyName`

try this for your current problem

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

   match /companies/{companyName=**}{
        allow read,write: if isUserAuthorized(companyName,get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(companyName)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company) ;
   }
  }
}
function isUserAuthorized(requestedCompanyName,userCompanyName) {
  return requestedCompanyName == userCompanyName;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it but what if someone creates a company that matches a collection name. Does it mean he will be able to update any collection with his company’s name?

Comment: for that you need to save the company with unique push keys and also save it inside the user. and check the companyId == user.companyId

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but any chance you would know the root cause of why the current rule won't work. What you have suggested seems to be best work around

Comment: may that `==true` in the rule, you can return the function true or false within  that function. and also use the `||` trick in my solution. its a workaround for some bug in firestore beta

Comment: In your first solution, the rule does not compile by saying unexpected `$` at character 133 which is the `$` sign at `[$(companyName)]` removing it and trying

Comment: put it in quotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158420/discussion-between-sap-and-hareesh).